# How do you unfold this summation factor?

Tags: recurrence-relations

This is from [Concrete mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201558025) page 27:

[image]

If we apply $s_n = s_{n-1} a_{n-1} / b_n$ recursively, at last we will need to know $s_0$, but how did it disappear in eq. 2.11?

Answer (score 1):

There is no error. You omitted a key part of the sentence:

> The relation $s_n=s_{n-1}a_{n-1}/b_n$ can be unfolded to tell us that the fraction $$s_n=\frac{a_{n-1}a_{n-2}\ldots a_1}{b_nb_{n-1}\ldots b_2}\;,\tag{2.11}$$ or any convenient constant multiple of this value, will be a suitable summation factor.

Here $(2.11)$ is actually a **definition** of $s_n$ for $n\ge 2$: it defines a sequence $\langle s_n:n\ge 2\rangle$ that satisfies the recurrence $s_n=s_{n-1}a_{n-1}/b_n$ and hence can be used as a summation factor, as can any constant multiple of it. In fact, using the convention that an empty product is $1$, it defines $s_n$ for $n\ge 1$, since it makes $s_1=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the relation iteratively:
\begin{equation*}
  s_n = \frac{s_{n-1}a_{n-1}}{b_n} = \frac{\frac{s_{n-2}a_{n-2}}{b_{n-1}}a_{n-1}}{b_n}
     = \frac{s_{n-2}a_{n-1}a_{n-2}}{b_n}b_{n-1}.
\end{equation*}
If you continue, eventually you will get to
\begin{equation*}
  s_n = \frac{a_{n-1}a_{n-2}\cdots a_1}{b_nb_{n-1}\cdots b_2}s_0.
\end{equation*}

Comment: I know, but in the textbook there is no $s_0$.

Comment: I suspect it's just a typo in the book. Unless you somehow know that $s_0 = 1$.

Comment: @rogerl: No typo: see my answer.